# How to delete unnecessary underline in html code?

Tags: html, css

I have a strange underline beneath my summary headline. I would like to ask if there is a way to remove it.
My problem looks like this:
[image: I am concerned about the less visible underline just under my text]

My code for this section looks like this:

```css
details>summary {
  list-style-type: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

details>summary::-webkit-details-marker {
  display: none;
}

details>summary::after {
  content: '+ ';
  float: right;
}

details[open]>summary::after {
  content: '- ';
  float: right;
}

details>summary {
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 20px
}

details[open]>summary {
  margin-bottom: 20px
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4 {
  display: inline;
}

p {
  text-align: justify;
}
```

```html
<details>
  <summary style="font-size: 18px; ">
    <h2>My H2</h2>
  </summary>
  <h3 style="margin-left: 3vw; ">Another data</h3>
  </details>
```

This happens just for my H2 and H1 tags and not for any more tags.
It happens just when my window is narrower than half of my screen.
Thanks for the answers; I will provide more information if necessary.

Comment: Just remove `border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.3);`...

Comment: @somethinghere This would remove the line I need to have (the more visible line). I need to remove the default line, which is displayed just below the text

Comment: Your `<details>` element is unclosed in your snippet, rendering your HTML invalid.

Comment: Which browser are you observing that in? Renders correctly in Safari 15.6.1, latest Chrome/Edge and latest Firefox (MacOS).

Comment: @connexo Ah, sorry, my bad, it should be fixed now. In my original code, I have it.

Comment: Voting to close as this is not reproducible on any on the big browsers.

Comment: @connexo I use Microsoft Edge, and I don't see it in Chrome. However, I would like to have it similar in all circumstances.

Comment: Which Edge version? Edge has been using the very same engine as Chrome has, for years now. Are you talking the very outdated and irrelevant *old* Edge?

Comment: @connexo I use Microsoft Edge Version 105.0.1343.27

Comment: It renders just fine in my Edge Version 105.0.1343.33 (arm64).

Comment: @connexo I found the issue; it happens when your window is narrower than half of the screen. In both browsers.

Comment: I do not see the problem on Chrome/Edge on Windows10 whatever I do to the window size. When you see it does it come and go if you zoom in/out?

Comment: @AHaworth Yeah, it's a problem of zooming in and out. However, I have resolved the issue now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved the issue. This problem occurs just for h1 and h2. However, it is possible to just change the headline tag to h3 and change the attributes to match h2 or h1.

Comment: Do you know why this happens? And what would stop it happening on some devices with other element types?

Comment: @AHaworth, I tried it on Chrome, Edge Windows (all zooms), iOS Safari and macOS Safari, so I suppose it's solved now. I don't have any more browsers. However, I believe these are so different; I would find out if the problem was still in place

Comment: @AHaworth, and why does this happen? No clue, I suppose, this happens because of rendering of the HTML in different zoom changes at some point.

Comment: Yes, I've seen it happen when the system has to decide how to map part pixels. 1 CSS pixel is rendered by several screen pixels on modern devices and sometimes a screen pixel can get 'left behind' - bit like a rounding error. I don't absolutely know that that was your problem because I couldn't reproduce it to experiment.